# Choose between 2 different MarshallingHttpMessageConverter instances based on path or parameter

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

**Scenario**:

In a Spring MVC controller (within a SpringBoot 1.2.5 microservice) I have an endpoint which returns a `JAXBElement<?>` which is marshalled to XML via a configured `MarshallingHttpMessageConverter` bean.  This works perfectly fine and currently does not perform validation against any schemas - it just spits out an XML representation of a domain object.

**Problem**

What I would like to be able to do on a per-request basis is specify whether validation should be performed during marshalling, so I can report any problems to the client - but still have the option to simply marshall with no validation.  Modifying the underlying `Jaxb2Marshaller` to do the validation is no problem, I just set the appropriate schema with `setSchema` and it works.

Given that `MarshallingHttpMessageConverter` works with a single marshaller instance that is either configured to validate or not, and content negotiation is based on the accept header, how can I modify the setup to facilitate *selective* validation per request (based on a query parameter or path) - preferably whilst still relying on Spring's content-negotiation magic to do the 'hard work'?

Answer (score 0):

As a (hopefully temporary) workaround, I have bypassed the auto content-negotiation provided by `MarshallingHttpMessageConverter`, instead creating two separate `Jaxb2Marshaller` beans, one which validates and one which doesn't, and using them directly within the controller method to marshall to a `StringResult`, then returning that as a `HttpEntity<String>`.  More manual steps required, but it works and I can easily switch between validating / not validating based on a request parameter (or whatever).

I won't accept this answer just in case anyone else comes up with a cleaner solution.